# Check for amount of registrations in application

Tags: mysql, validation

I'm making a small Java program that connects to a database using NetBeans.

I can register a certain amount of customers into a quiz (this amount is also an attribute in my database).

To this I wish to add a kind of validation: if the number of registrations reaches a given amount, the quiz gets full and further registration should be disallowed.

How can I check if the amount is reached so the user will get a message if the quiz is full (such as `"Max amount of registrations reached"`).

I thought maybe I could use a for-loop, but I don't know where to really start.

I would appreciate some help.
(in case I forgot some information, please ask me for it)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the following Database model, you can easily just query this rather than to keep track of it in your programming language.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ...
} 

CREATE TABLE `events` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `maxUsers` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `date` some timestamp
} 

CREATE TABLE `participants` (
    `userId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `eventId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `paymentState` VARCHAR(100) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `wonTooMuchStuffLastYear` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
}
```

Your `checkIfMaxUsersReached()` query will look like this.

```
SELECT
    count(userId)
FROM
    participants
WHERE
    eventId = 12;
```

Events.id 12 is the quiz you're trying to check if there're more spots available.

vice versa now you're also able to create the function `haveYouSignedUpForTooManyEvents()`, in which you check if a user has subscribed for his max allowed events this year alredy.

```
SELECT
    count(eventId)
FROM
    participants
WHERE
    userId = 3; //user.id 3 = Johnny.
```

I think you're more looking for a database thing than for a java/programming language thing.
I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First Let Us create the table with registration id and the events as :

```
CREATE TABLE QUIZ
(
RID NUMBER,
EVENT VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Now , I had inserted some sample data's

```
INSERT INTO QUIZ(RID,EVENT)
VALUES(1,'QUIZ');
INSERT INTO QUIZ(RID,EVENT)
VALUES(2,'QUIZ');
INSERT INTO QUIZ(RID,EVENT)
VALUES(3,'QUIZ');
INSERT INTO QUIZ(RID,EVENT)
VALUES(4,'QUIZ');
COMMIT;
```

Then, Use this simple procedure to find the registration count

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VALID(E_NAME IN QUIZ.EVENT%TYPE)
AS
RN SYS_REFCURSOR;
ENAME VARCHAR2(25);
CNT NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   ENAME := E_NAME;
OPEN RN FOR 
  SELECT MAX(R) FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY RID) R FROM QUIZ 
  WHERE EVENT =   ENAME);
 FETCH RN INTO CNT;
 IF CNT <= 10 THEN  /* consider maximum participants as ten */
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REGISTRATION IS AVAILABLE');
 ELSE
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REGISTRATION IS NOT AVAILABLE');
 END IF;
END;
/
```

And You will get the result like this

```
SQL> EXEC VALID('QUIZ');
```

REGISTRATION IS AVAILABLE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.